# Bolt URL generation using slugs and content types

Tags: url, slug, bolt-cms

i am using bolt and i have a question about the URL generation.

whenever i create a content type and with a singular_name or singular_slug and a slug. it shows in the URL like this: www.example.com/singular_name/slug

and i want it to be www.example.com/slug nothing more than that. when i try to use singular_slug, it does the same.

becouse how i read this it should not add the singular_slug in the URL.

i hope someone can explain this to me or help me find a solution.

Edit. i understand the documentation of singular_slug now it just replaces the singular name. this still doesnt help much for my problem but still.

[image] it show this but i want the "vervolg 2/" to not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is set up an additional binding route for a contenttype you want on base, e.g.:

```
pagebinding:
    path: /{slug}
    defaults:
        _controller: controller.frontend:record
        contenttypeslug: page
    contenttype: pages
```